# Updating model from the collection

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js, model, underscore.js

I am very new to backbone. I am trying to display some JSON content into this HTML template. Created one collection and fetch the JSON file data. On render method of the collection, updating the model, which is bind with the view.

Kindly suggest where is the problem.

```
<script type="text/template" id="banner_template">
     <div class="span8"><img src="<%=img%>"></div>
     <div class="span4 bg-lightRedcustom no-margin"><div class="bnrPadding"><h2 class="fg-white"><%=html%></h2></div></div>
</script> 

 <div id="banner_container"> </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
var BannerModel=Backbone.Model.extend({id:"",img:"",html:""});
var bannerModel=new BannerModel();
  var BannerCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model:BannerModel,
          url:"res/banner-res.json",
          parse: function (response) {
            return response;
            },
        render: function() {         
                this.fetch({success:function(a){                     
                     _.each(a.toJSON(),function(obj){                           
                        if(obj.id=="services1.html"){bannerModel.set({id:obj.id,img:obj.img,html:obj.html});
                            console.log(bannerModel);
                        }                      
                        });
                   }}
                );
            return this;
         },
      });
var bannerCollection=new BannerCollection();
bannerCollection.render();

 var BannerView = Backbone.View.extend({
         initialize: function(){  
             this.render();          
         },               
         template: _.template($("#banner_template").html()),
         render: function(){                
             this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()) );             
         }
     });   

 var banner_view = new BannerView({ el: $("#banner_container"),model:bannerModel});
```

**Update 1**

**

Here is my code which worked

```
<script type="text/template" id="banner_template">
 <div class="span8"><img src="<%=img%>"></div>
 <div class="span4 bg-lightRedcustom no-margin"><div class="bnrPadding"><h2 class="fg-white"><%=html%></h2></div></div>
</script> 
 <div id="banner_container"> </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var BannerCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({        
          url:"res/banner-res.json"
      });
var bannerCollection=new BannerCollection();

var BannerModel=Backbone.Model.extend({});
var bannerModel=new BannerModel({});
var BannerView = Backbone.View.extend({
         el: $("#banner_container"),
         initialize: function(){             
             this.model.on('change',this.render,this);
             bannerCollection.fetch({success:function(a){                                 
                     _.each(a.toJSON(),function(obj){                           
                        if(obj.bid=="services1.html"){                          
                            bannerModel.set({img:obj.img,html:obj.html});                                               
                        }                      
                      });
                   }}
                );                      
         },      
         model:bannerModel,         
         template: _.template($("#banner_template").html()),
         render: function(){  
            this.$el.html(this.template(bannerModel.toJSON()) );   
         }
     });         
var banner_view = new BannerView({model:bannerModel});
</script>
```

Comment: We can't suggest where the problem is if you don't even tell us what's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few problems I see right off the bat:

1. You define BannerModel with this argument: `{id:"",img:"",html:""}`.  Is that meant to be default values?  If so, it needs to be set under the 'defaults' property, like: `{ defaults: {id:"",img:"",html:""} }`.  Actually, it doesn't seem necessary at all.
2. In `BannerCollection`, you pass `BannerModel` as the 'model' property.  It needs to be an *instance* of a Model, so pass it `bannerModel`.
3. The parse function doesn't do anything the way you have it.  It's not required to have it, only when you want to pre-process the data from your API before it gets to your view.
4. You call `fetch()` from within the 'render' function.  This is not the right place for it.  In fact, Collections & Models don't have a render function at all.  Only Views do.  In your View, you can either put it in the 'initialize' method, or some other method you can call on demand.
5. In your fetch() success callback, you iterate through the collection and set the model on some condition.  First of all, by the time you get to the success callback, Backbone has *already* populated your collection with an array of bannerModel's.  This is what fetch() does.  It calls your API and automatically populates your Collection/Model with data.  If you want to intercept/parse that data before it is populated, that's what the parse() method is for.
6. You don't call render() on a Collection, you call it on Views.
7. One last thing.  Your code seems to imply that the value of the model's `id` attribute will be a text string such as 'services1.html'.  The 'id' should be reserved for some unique key - typically, it's an integer or maybe a GUID.  Backbone will actually look for this attribute by default and use it as the unique identifier for the model.  If you want to use some other value, you can use `idAttribute` - http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute